# Error on DS-160 submission

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

I submitted a DS-160 (U.S. Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application) and received a confirmation and a barcode, but then wasn't able to make a payment because an error message said my barcode was already taken. However, I was forwarded to the page where I retrieve my DS-160. I continued and received a new confirmation and a new barcode, but this time I was able to make the payment and receive my instruction sheet along with the last barcode on it.

Do I need to take both confirmation pages with me to the interview?

On my instruction sheet I also made a mistake and entered my surnames twice, for example, *John Matthew Brown Brown*. Will this affect my interview?

Answer (score 5):

You should bring only the barcode corresponding to the application that you want the consular section to consider.

When you arrive for your interview, let the consular officer know of the error in your name. They will either correct it on the spot (most likely for a minor error like this), or they will give you instructions on how to correct it yourself and schedule a new appointment.